# Laravel allocate LIKE query not giving results

Tags: sql-like, laravel-6

I am using a `LIKE` query to show results from the `Posts` table where the `category` field matches one of the array elements in the `Users` table's skills field. But it is not giving me any results.

**Controller**

```php
class TaskerController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }

    public function tasks()
    {
        $skills = Auth::user()->skills;
        $posts = Post::where('category', 'LIKE', '%'.$skills.'%');

        return view('task')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not concatenate array like a string.

Since your skills is an array use **whereIn** method

```
    public function tasks(){ 
       $skills = Auth::user()->skills;
       $skills = explode (",", $skills); // since you got comma separated skills you need to convert to array
       //$skills =['skill1', 'skill2', 'skill3'];
       $posts = Post::whereIn('category', $skills ); 
       return view('task')->with('posts', $posts);
    }
```

Comment: This error appeared:      Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\multi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 907

Comment: Make Sure $skills is an array

Comment: I have done this:                                                                                                                           public function tasks(){
 
     $skills = Auth::user()->skills;
  
       $posts = Post::WhereIn('category',   [$skills]);
       dd($posts->toSql(), $posts->getBindings());
       exit;
     
        return view('task')->with('posts', $posts);
    }

Comment: it shows:                                                                                                                           "select * from `posts` where `category` in (?)"
array:1 [▼
  0 => "Electrition,Plumber"
]                                                                                                                                      but not giving desired results

Comment: Oh you have comma sperated string, so it won't as expected. See the updated answer